# jspring 4.0x json response wrong with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

My Controller:

```html
        @RestController
public class ClawerController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){        
        return "hello";
    }

 @RequestMapping(value="getNewsByCategoryId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<News> getNewsByCategoryId(String categoryId) {
  List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
  try {
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://news.cqu.edu.cn/news/article/list.php?catid="+categoryId).get();
   Elements liphoto = doc.select("div.liphoto div.row1");
   for (Element row : liphoto) {
    Element link = row.select("a").first();
    Element img = row.select("img").first();
    News news = new News(link.attr("href"), img.attr("alt"), "", "http://news.cqu.edu.cn/"+img.attr("src"));
    newsList.add(news);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return newsList;
 }
}
```

My web.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
 <display-name>project03</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Spring Configuration file:

```html
<p>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.echo.spider.controller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</beans>
</p>
```

I access my controller using below:

```
http://localhost:8080/project03/getNewsByCategoryId?categoryId=46
```

Then the response I get is 406：

```html
HTTP Status 406 -
type Status report
message
description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

I access my controller using below:

```
http://localhost:8080/project03/hello
```

the response is right hello.
What's wrong with me?Tks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem.The reason It didn't work is that my controller returned a list or object data.
1.I should add jackson-annotations、jackson-core and jackson-databind jar into my classpath.
2.After that,I changed my servlet-context.xml into that:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
        
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:component-scan base-package="org.echo.spider.controller" />
 
 <bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"
  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
  <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
   <list>
    <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
   <list>
    <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" /><!-- json转换器 -->
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

That's okay.